# CSS hover: doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm setting up a navigation bar by doing this:

```
<div id="globalheader">
        <ul id="globalnav">
            <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Please note I stripped a lot more items because it would make this example too large.

Now, here's my CSS:

```
/* GLOBALHEADER */
#globalheader { width: 506px; height: 36.75px; margin: 18px auto; position: relative; z-index: 9998; }
#globalheader #globalnav { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#globalheader #globalnav li { display: inline; }
#globalheader #globalnav li a { float: left; width: 101.2px; height: 0; padding-top: 36.75px; overflow: hidden; }
#globalheader #globalnav li a,
#globalheader #globalnav { background-image: url(navbar.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; }


/* BUTTONS */
#globalheader #globalnav li#home a { background-position: 0 0; }

/* OVER STATES */
#globalheader #globalnav li#home a:hover { background-position: 0 -37; }

/* PRESSED STATES */
#globalheader #globalnav li#home a:active { background-position: 0 -73.5px; }
```

Now, there are more items (as I said previously) that I took out just for space's sake.

Here's the problem:  The buttons display fine, and also the `active` state.  However, `hover` doesn't seem to work at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: which browsers (and versions) are you testing with?

Comment: And yes, I realize I should probably make my navbar that doesn't use decimals. :)

Comment: @Spudley Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: Off-topic: Your CSS contains many selectors with multiple ID references (ie the ones with `#` symbols). These should be unnecessary: Because an ID should be unique in a page, you should be able to identify an element by only specifying a single ID. So a selector like `#globalheader #globalnav li#home` should be exactly the same as simply saying `#home`, which should select a single specific element in the DOM. The way you're using them looks more like the way classes are supposed to be used. If you need to use them this way, you should be using classes instead.

Comment: @Spudley Makes sense!  Yes, that seems right.  It sure will make my CSS cleaner, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding px to your position:

```
#globalheader #globalnav li#home a:hover { background-position: 0 -37px; }
```

Comment: Bingo!  Did the trick quite nicely.  Not sure how I forgot about that. :)  I'll accept the answer once it lets me.

Comment: It's always hard to see those type of errors when you've been staring at the code for hours :-)

Comment: running the code through a validator would pick up things like this. but agreed with @wajiw; its an easy thing to miss.